# __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'receiver'?

Tags: python, sqlite

Im trying to get the data of a word through database with sqlite3 and python but when i try to call the read_from_db function, i have this error _init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'receiver'. I cant seem to find what happened 
heres the code

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('yeet1.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()


class Ui_WordWindow(object):


    def __init__(self, receiver):  #Inherit user-input word from another window

        self.receiver = receiver        
        print(self.receiver) #Checking if it worked correctly

    def read_From_db(self): #Read and print out data of user-input word

         cursor.execute(('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Meaning = ?', self.receiver))
         data = cursor.fetchall()
         print(data)




window2 = Ui_WordWindow()
window2.read_From_db()
cursor.close()
conn.close
```

Comment: when you say window2 = Ui_WordWindow() , you are invoking the constructor i.e the __init__, so you need to pass the object receiver , like this window2 = Ui_WordWindow(receiver)

Comment: Hey! thanks for the comment but after i changed it, theres this new error: NameError: name 'receiver' is not defined

Comment: you are just passing "receiver" as a string? it should be the actual receiver object

Comment: yes i am passing receiver as a string, is there something wrong?sorry,  im pretty new to python

Comment: your receiver should be an object of some type

Comment: is it possible for you to give me an example? i didnt quite understand that

Answer (score 1):

You declare the `__init__` method of the class `Ui_WordWindow` like so:

```
def __init__(self, receiver):  #Inherit user-input word from another window
```

And it *does* have a parameter receiver. The error you get indicates that when constructing a `Ui_WordWindow` you should provide exactly one parameter and that should be the value for receiver.

I.e. this line:

```
window2 = Ui_WordWindow()
```

Should in fact be:

```
window2 = Ui_WordWindow(receiver)
```

where receiver is a valid value for receiver.

Comment: Hey! thanks for the quick reply, i changed it like you said but this happened: NameError: name 'receiver' is not defined

Comment: `where receiver is a valid value for receiver.` this is part of my answer. Here you should already have a variable `receiver` defined and it should store a valid instance of what you call receiver.

Answer (score 0):

The receiver object = "some value"

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('yeet1.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()


class Ui_WordWindow(object):


    def __init__(self, receiver):  #Inherit user-input word from another window

        self.receiver = receiver        
        print(self.receiver) #Checking if it worked correctly
        #when you print self.receiver it means the value which you are passing say for example "test"  

    def read_From_db(self): #Read and print out data of user-input word

         cursor.execute(('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Meaning = ?', "test"))

         # now the query becomes select * from mytable where meaning = 'test'
         # the value 'test' is being passed by the receiver object and you need to provide that value

         data = cursor.fetchall()
         print(data)




window2 = Ui_WordWindow(receiver) # which has some value ex 'test'
window2.read_From_db()
cursor.close()
conn.close
```

you need to brush up on **object oriented** approach.
try reading from this: [python object oriented](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/object-oriented-programming)

Comment: Thank you for putting in time for this but if i did that, the program wouldnt automatically search for that word ?

Comment: once, you go though the tutorial you may understand where you are going wrong.

Comment: Hey, i read through the tutorial, it helped me but i dont think i learned what i want. If i want to make receiver an object, i would have to literally give it an ex value (like your code) in the code but not the user. I want to make it so that the user-input word become an object itself, is that possible?